# How to prove $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{(k+1)} k \binom nk=0$

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, summation, binomial-coefficients

How to prove this identity?

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{(k+1)} k \binom nk=0$$ This is George Casella statistical inference textbook exercise 1.27 (c). I have no idea to prove.

Comment: Strong hint: Use the identity $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$.

Comment: @Yanko still have no idea

Comment: @Jonathen In doubt, always use induction for this kind of problem.

Comment: Ah seems like you've edit the question...

Comment: Alternatively use  the identity $(X+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}X^k$.

Comment: Use the binomial theorem to expand $(1 - x)^n$, differentiate both sides of the resulting equation w.r.t. $x$ and then put $x = 1$.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank for your idea. I almost succeed. But I get $(-1)^{n-k}$, not the desired $(-1)^{k+1}$

Comment: Multiplied by $(-1)^{2k-n+1}$ both sides? It seems a weird step for me.

Comment: It's not really weird: it's just about the symmetries in the binomial theorem. If I'd written $(x - 1)^n$, I think you'd have got straight there.

Comment: Something is not correct in the identity, because it is not true for $n=1$ .You have to say that $n\geq2$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binomial coefficient series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} k \binom nk=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399464/binomial-coefficient-series-sum-limits-k-1n-1k1-k-binom-nk-0)

Comment: @boojum You are right. Same. And that answers my question. I tried to search, but I didn't search the same question. Sad. otherwise I don't need to ask the quesrtion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} k \binom{n}{k} 
&= n \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1} \binom{n-1}{k-1} \\
&= n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^k \binom{n-1}{k} \\
&= n (1-1)^{n-1} \\
&= n \cdot 0^{n-1} \\
&= \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $n=1$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

We assume $n > 1$.  Start with the Binomial Theorem:
$$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} x^k$$
Differentiate:
$$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} x^{k-1}$$
Set $x=-1$ and observe that $(-1)^{k-1}=(-1)^{k+1}$:
$$\begin{align}
n(1-1)^{n-1} &= \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k-1}\\
0 &= \sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} (-1)^{k+1}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

First we notice that the identity is not true for $n=1$. So we prove it for $n\geq\,2$. We use induction and the identity:

$\dbinom{n+1}{k}=\dbinom{n}{k}+\dbinom{n}{k-1}$.

Assume it is true for $n$. Now we write the $n+1$ statement as:

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1}k\dbinom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k+1}k\dbinom{n}{k-1}$.

Take the first term and notice that for $k=n+1$ the $n+1$ term is zero, by the definition of the factorial coefficient. Therefore we are left with

$\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}k\dbinom{n}{k}$ which is zero by the assumption of the induction.

Now we must prove that the second term is also zero. Set $k-1=m$ and get

$\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m+2}(m+1)\dbinom{n}{m}$=$\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m}(m+1)\dbinom{n}{m}$=$\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m}m\dbinom{n}{m}+\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m}\dbinom{n}{m}$ but $-\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m+1}m\dbinom{n}{m}=0$

by the assumption of the induction (it makes no difference to add $m=0$).

So we are left with $\sum_{m=0}^{n}(-1)^{m}\dbinom{n}{m}$. But this is just (by Newton's binomial theorem) $[1+(-1)]^{n}=0$.

Thus the $n$-statement implies the $n+1$-statement and we are done!